# Windows (un)installer dialog not localized

Tags: wix, windows-installer, uninstallation

On a Chinese (CHS) version of Windows (XP, 7, probably others), when you uninstall our product, the standard windows uninstall progress dialog comes up in **English** (un-localized). As the uninstall progresses, the dialog refreshes and the text shows up in Chinese.

We have provided transforms for the various language, and if you apply our CHS transform manually in Orca, ProductLanguage (in the Property table) changes from 1033 to 1028 as expected.

I'm new to this stuff, so I don't understand if the initial display of un-localized strings is a known bug in Microsoft's uninstaller, or if we're doing something wrong.

Can someone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really influence that dialog from your MSI package - it is a system dialog and it only depends on the current Display Language (`Region and Language >> Keyboards and Languages >> Choose a display language`). Hence, if you are sure the display language is correct, but you still see the English text at the very beginning - then this is how the system works.